# How to open link in php code being executed via command line

Tags: php

```php
header("location:http;//")
```

Above line does not seem to work when executing PHP scripts from command line. How best can I open links via command line?

Comment: The line of php does not make sense regardless of commndline or otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very hastily and quickly tested method might be to use `exec` passing in the path to a known browser with the url as it's argument - seemed to work ok.

```
<?php
    $url='https://www.google.co.uk';
    $cmd=sprintf( '%%userprofile%%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe %s', $url );
    exec( $cmd );
?>
```

Thanks to @Álvaro's comment the above can be simplified further( on Windows at least )

```
<?php
    $url='https://www.google.co.uk';
    $cmd=sprintf( 'start %s',$url );
    exec( $cmd );
?>
```

Comment: On Windows, `start https://www.google.co.uk` will open the default browser.

Comment: did not know that - would make the whole exercise even simpler '-)

Answer (score 1):

The solution provided above would only work for windows. IT would not work on mac OS . Here is a more general solution

```
public function  open(string $url): void
{
    switch (PHP_OS) {
        case 'Darwin':
            $opener = 'open';
            break;
        case 'WINNT':
            $opener = 'start';
            break;
        default:
            $opener = 'xdg-open';
    }

    exec(sprintf('%s %s', $opener, $url));
}
```

Comment: Please give credits to the original author: https://github.com/matt-allan/open/blob/master/src/open.php

Answer (score 0):

`header()` is HTTP-related only and is used to tell what headers should by returned by the server to the client's browser which performed the request. `Location`, in particular, simply means `Hey ! Check out this place instead: xxxxx`.

The client's browser, in turn, will decide by itself if it chooses to follow this advice or not (it usually does) but at no time, the served fetches these informations to re-serve them again to its client.

So the best way to do is to use your script throughout a web browser instead (as it supposed to be). If you want to « open links » from a command line, simply type your browser's executable name followed by an URL (e.g.: `firefox http://www.stackoverflow.com`).

If what you want to do instead is fetching files or specific pages from a remote web server, use a command line client such as **`wget`** or **`curl`** instead.